# What is the difference between 'I can't imagine...' and 'I don't imagine...'?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context

Swan says in his book *Advanced Oxford Grammar* that we usually use this construction:

> I don't imagine + affirmative verb
>
> E.g. **I don't Imagine** John will read the instructions I sent him.

I've been comparing this construction with **I can't imagine ...**. My question is, do they have the same meaning, even though they are differed by the verb and modal?

I've tried to search related problems involving **I can't imagine... ** provided here:

1. [can-t-begin-to-imagine-understand-explain-etc.](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/can-t-begin-to-imagine-understand-explain-etc)
2. [I can't imagine John is driving a car.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/120953/110852)

Both links gave me a sense that those forms I've mentioned before are the same in meaning. However, I want to know if it turns out they are extremely different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"I don't imagine..." states without emphasis that, in your opinion, something is probably untrue.

"I can't imagine..." adds emphasis by suggesting that, in your opinion, something is vanishingly unlikely.